# Exporting output to file, incrementing file name per date

Tags: python, file, export, output, increment

What is a command that I can use in Python, without using the command line, that, instead of printing the program's output, sends it to a file? Additionally, if the file is named per day (2019-03-11) (not necessarily today's date), how do I increment the name of the file?

Comment: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: If you're using an UNIX command line you can simply do from the command line itself: `python my_script.py > output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

How does the date change throughout the execution of your code?

If it just gets the date from your data set, your code should appear like this:

```
def toFile(output, date):
    fileName = "{}.txt".format(date)

    with open(fileName, 'w') as file:
        file.write(output)
```

If you require to increment over a certain period (i.e. Each other day), you'll use the same idea from above, but using this code to generate your date:

```
import datetime

#The idea here is to increment our current date by a given number of days (of course, you can change it as you need).

def incrementDate(date, offset):
    #Here, we convert our string date into a datetime object. Then, we add the offset (in days) to our date.

    dateFormat = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    offsetFormat = datetime.timedelta(days=offset)
    newDate = dateFormat + offsetFormat

    #Finally, we convert it back to string and return.
    return newDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
        #First create a blank txt file in the directory as your code file. and name it filename.txt. If you want to add to the file add a 'a' mode to the open.     
  def save():

    filename = '2019-01-01.txt'
    output = 'Your own output'
    file = open(filename, 'w')
    file.write(output)
    file.close()

    import os
    os.rename(filename, '2019-01-02.txt')

    file = open('file.txt', 'r')
    reader = file.read()
    print(reader)
    file.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't address the date part of the question

Comment: when you run save(), you get the following output:
Your own output

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on the `with` context manager for working with files. Also, please don't answer low quality questions.

Comment: I just updated it, try that. Change it appropriately to your question.

Comment: I tried this and replacing 'Your own output' but it didn't export anything